# Signal: SIGTRAP (Trace/breakpoint trap)

Tags: c, матрицы, heap

Почему моя программа во время отладки с бесконечными Warning'ами работает, высчитывает обратную матрицу(Правильно причём), а вот когда запускаешь её без отладки она просто не отвечает и VS пишет "Куча повреждена". Посмотрите пожалуйста:

> **Signal: SIGTRAP (Trace/breakpoint trap)** ("Бесконечный" Warning)

```
int p = 0; //Кол-во перестановок

double **scan_matr(int *m, int *n) {
    printf("Введите размеры матрицы :");
    scanf("%i", m); scanf("%i", n);
    printf("\nВведите матрицу:\n");
    double **matr = (double **) malloc(*m * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i) {
        matr[i] = (double *) malloc(*n * sizeof(double));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *n; ++j) {
            scanf("%lf", &(matr[i][j]));
        }
        puts("");
    }
    return matr;
}

void print_matr(double **matr, int m, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            printf("%13.4f",matr[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");
}

// Перестановка (swap) строк матрицы a и b длины n
void swap_lines(double *a, double *b, size_t n) {
    double *c = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = b[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i] = c[i];

    free(c);
}

void copy_line(double *src, double *dst, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        dst[i] = src[i];
}

void mul(double *a, double b, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        a[i] *= b;
}

void add(double *from, double *to, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        to[i] += from[i];
}

void solveGauss(double **matr, int m, int n) {
    double *tmp_line = malloc(m * sizeof(double));

    for (int k = 0; k < m; ++k) {
        int max = k;

        for (int j = k; j < m; ++j) //Находим максимальный элемент в столбце на k'ом шаге
            if (abs(matr[max][k]) < abs(matr[j][k]))
                max = j;

        if(max>k){
            //Обмен строк max и k
            swap_lines(matr[max],matr[k],n); p=p+1;
            max = k;
        }

        for (int i = k+1; i < m; ++i) {
            double h = -(matr[i][k]/matr[max][k]);
            copy_line(matr[k], tmp_line,n);
            mul(tmp_line,h,n);
            add(tmp_line,matr[i],n);
            puts("");
        }
    }

    free(tmp_line);
}

void solveInverse(double **matr, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        matr[i] = (double *)realloc(matr[i],(n+n) * sizeof(double));
        for (int j = n; j < n+n; ++j)
            matr[i][j] = 0;
        matr[i][n+i] = 1;
    }

    solveGauss(matr, n, n+n);

    double **B=(double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (int j = 0; j < n+1; ++j) {
        B[j] = (double *) malloc((n+1) * sizeof(double));
    }

    double **result = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        result[j] = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0, l = 0; k < n+n; ++k) {
                if((k<n)||(k==n+i)){
                    B[j][l++] = matr[j][k];
                }
            }
        }

        double *x = solveSLAU(B,n);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            result[j][i] = x[j];
        }

        free(x);
    }

    print_matr(result,n,n);
}

int main() {
    int m, n;

    //Обратная матрица
    double **A = scan_matr(&m,&n);
    solveInverse(A,m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Строку бы хоть указали на `бесконечными Warning'ами работает`, уж больно много текста :) а так, очевидно что что то не так с выделением памяти и вы выходите за выделенные границы.

Comment: В вашем случае, получается 2 массива, по этому: `double ***matr = ..` и `matr[i] = (double**) malloc(*n * sizeof(double*))` и потом так же в цикле: `matr[i][n] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double))` по количеству `n`.. ну и так далее, по всему коду..

Comment: @NewView вылетает в на освобождении памяти free(tmp_line);

Comment: Вылетает по тому что вы уже испортили память выйдя за границы выделения, может начать вылетать в другом месте, это уже не суть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема связана с некорректным выделением памяти, попробуйте этот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct matrix_t
{
    int m,n;
    double ***matr;
};

int scan_matr(struct matrix_t *matrix)
{
    int m, n;

    printf("Введите размеры матрицы :");
    scanf("%i", &matrix->m);
    if (matrix->m <= 0)
        return 0;

    scanf("%i", &matrix->n);
    if (matrix->n <= 0)
        return 0;

    printf("\nВведите матрицу:\n");
    matrix->matr = (double***) malloc(matrix->m * sizeof(double*));

    for (m = 0; m < matrix->m; m++)
    {
        matrix->matr[m] = (double**) malloc(matrix->n * sizeof(double*));

        for (n = 0; n < matrix->n; n++)
        {
            matrix->matr[m][n] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));
            scanf("%lf", matrix->matr[m][n]);
            printf("\t%d/%d) = [%f]\n", m, n, *matrix->matr[m][n]);
        }

    }
    return 1;
}


void prn_matr(struct matrix_t *matrix)
{
    int m, n;
    printf("\nMatrix %dx%d\n", matrix->m, matrix->n);

    for (m = 0; m < matrix->m; m++)
    {
        printf("\tMatrix slot [%d]\n\t\t", m);
        for (n = 0; n < matrix->n; n++)
        {
            printf("[%f] ", *matrix->matr[m][n]);
        }
        printf("\n\tMatrix slot end\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct matrix_t matrix = {0};
    int ret = scan_matr(&matrix);

    printf("return %d\n", ret);

    prn_matr(&matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

У вас два массива: 'm' и 'n'. В matr содержится массив m, в каждом элементе m содержится массив n, а вот в нем уже располагаются значения double. Под это надо выделять память как в примере выше.

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для упрощения понимания, можно для себя визуализировать матрицу, например 2х3:

```
    matr = {
       m[0] = {n[0] = 0,n[1] = 0,n[2] = 0},
       m[1] = {n[0] = 0,n[1] = 0,n[2] = 0}
    }
```

В реальном коде конечно стоит проверять возвращаемые значения `malloc`, `scanf` ит.д.

Answer (score 1):

```
double **B=(double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
for (int j = 0; j < n+1; ++j) {
    B[j] = (double *) malloc((n+1) * sizeof(double));
}
```

Итак, в `B` места для `n` элементов. Условие `j < n+1` допускает `j==n`. Куда вы будете писать при этом `B[j]`? За границами массива...

Код и в самом деле длинный, так что не скажу, что это единственная ошибка...

А, вот еще, например:

```
double **matr = (double **)malloc(*m * sizeof(double *));
for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i) {
    matr[i] = (double *)malloc(*n * sizeof(double));
```

Смотрите - выделили память для `*m` указателей, а пишете их `*n`.

Вобщем, повнимательнее с памятью! И еще - в Visual Studio в меню есть такой "Анализ кода" - там не всегда замечается все, а замеченное иногда бывает замечено зря, но посмотреть и подумать - имеет смысл...

И еще - пока смотрел - просто какой смысл при обмене строк выделять память для целой строки? Почему не просто в цикле менять `a[i]` и `b[i]` через одну временную переменную, а не через массив? Это не ошибка, это неэффективность :)

Comment: `выделили память для *m указателей, а пишете их *n` - не, там просто еще один массив  с `n` значениями. если я правильно суть кода понял..

Comment: @NewView `matr` после первой строчки содержит место для `*m` указателей. Далее - цикл от 0 до `*n`. И что будет, если `*n > *m`? Массивов с `*n` значениями там не один, а `*n`, а должно быть - `*m`.

Comment: Да, да, но потом должен идти массив с `n` количеством элементов. :) Судя по коду, посмотрите мой комментарий, что я имею в виду, переписывать тоже самое не вижу смысла.

Comment: @NewView Извините, не понимаю, что вы хотите сказать...

Comment: Там два масиива: 'm' и 'n'. В `matr` содержится массив `m`, в каждом элементе `m` содержится массив `n`, а вот в нем уже располагаются значения `double`.

Comment: @NewView Да какие массивы?! автор просто непонятно зачем передает адрес переменной вместо значения, только и всего... Нет там никаких **массивов** `m` и `n`...

Comment: как нету то? `scanf("%i", m); scanf("%i", n);`  - вот два числа для __двух__ массивов матрицы :( другой вопрос что автор не проверят полученные/ неполученные результаты этих операций.

Comment: Визуализировать матрицу 2х3:  `matr = { m[0] = {n[0] = 0,n[1] = 0,n[2] = 0}, m[1] =  {0,0,0} }`

Comment: @NewView По-моему, вы просто прикалываетесь... Я со своей стороны из дискуссии выхожу, мне смефуечками заниматься некогда...

Comment: Такое впечатление что мы разговариваем о разном коде, позднее поправлю код автора и выложу рабочую версию, спорить явно без пользы. Тут в споре не 'рождаеться истина' :)