# Создание и оперирование динамическим массивом из функции [СИ]

Tags: c, функции, динамические-массивы, main, динамические-структуры

Никак не пойму - сколько и где `*` должно быть.

```
// Структура, являющаяся элементами массива
struct token {
 unsigned int postindex;
 unsigned long long int bedeutung;
}

int main() {
 // Переменные
 struct token *token_dynmass;

 // Функция
 InputFiller(&(*token_dynmass));

 return 0;
}

char InputFiller(struct token **token_dynmass) {

 // Инициализация структуры
 *token_dynmass = (struct token*)malloc(4*sizeof(struct token));
 *token_dynmass = (struct token*)realloc((*token_dynmass),(4 *1.5*sizeof(struct token)));

 // Считываем индекс (ключ)
 scanf("%u", &(token_dynmass[0]->bedeutung));
 }
```

Проблема также состоит в том, что мне не просто нужно скормить функции дин. массив, но и сделать так, чтобы функция "меняла" его в main. Т.е. Чтоб после я мог, например, через printf вывести этот массив уже из main.

P.S. Знаю, что так не делают, но мне нужно разобраться с указателями.

P.P.S. `*token_dynmass` - динамический массив

Comment: `struct token **token_dynmass = (struct token**)malloc(4*sizeof(struct token*)); token_dynmass[0] = (struct token*)malloc(sizeof(struct token));` примерно так, ну и остальные элементы массива инициализировать по одному `[1], [2], [3]`

Comment: И лучше возвращать его из функции, а не таскать неинициализированный массив туда-сюда: `struct token **  InputFilter(void) { .. return token_dynmass;  }`

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879765/298154) вроде там подробно описал порядок действий при инициализации массивов.

Comment: @NewView: При чем здесь "по одному"? Выделяется память для обыкновенного одномерного массива. Откуда и зачем тут могут взяться множественные вызовы `malloc` "по одному"???

Comment: По одному, нагляднее, можно и целиком конечно, задача то объяснить что откуда вытекает вроде стояла. По очереди можно красиво расставить `*` для наглядности :)

Comment: @NewView: Не понимаю. Налицо попыка выделить память *для обыкновенного одномерного массива*. Как это можно сделать "по одному"?

Comment: Это урезанный кусок кода, поэтому следом за маллоком идёт реаллок

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте один и тот же вопрос снова и снова. Если вам непонятен ответ - не стоит отмечать его как принятый и тут же дублировать вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash♦: Код во втором вопросе был более правильным, чем в этом. Там было `InputFiller(&token_dynmass);`. Мой ответ относится именно к той, более правильной версии кода. Вы закрыли тот вопрос, и оставили этот, перенеся сюда мой ответ. Но в рамках этой версии кода мой ответ становится почти бессмыслен. Наверное, надо было оставлять именно тот вопрос и переносить ответы туда, а не наоборот.

Comment: @AnT я оставил самый старый из трех вопросов. Если бы выбрал другой - точно такая же ситуация была бы с ответом KoVadim :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

посмотрим на эту строку

```
struct token *token_dynmass;
```

тут объявляется указатель на структуру. Самой структуры ещё нет.

```
InputFiller(&(*token_dynmass));
```

конструкцией `*token_dynmass` пытаемся рызменовать - то есть, получить исходный объект по указателю. Но его нет. его ещё никто не создал. Сама функция требует двойного указателя, а у нас получается одинарный. ещё и похоже с UB.

Да, формально, там указатель, так как амперсанды и звездочки "обычно взаимоуничтожаются". Но разыменования указателя в "никуда" - это очень плохо.

Поэтому, самый быстрый фикс - это вызывать так

```
InputFiller(&token_dynmass);
```

То есть, token_dynmass указатель, а функции нужен двойной. Амперсанд как раз это и сделает.

Но внутри функции есть  умножение на 1.5. Да, там ещё есть 4 и все будет скорее всего хорошо, но лучше так не делать. Дело в том, что 1.5 * 4 будет 6, но с другими числами может получится чуточку меньше - это все таки вещественная арифметика.

Comment: Cпасибо, что разьяснили
Все зарадотало

Comment: А не подскажите - что в scanf пихать?

Comment: с указателями вроде там нормально, а вот вместо `%u` скорее всего нужно писать `%llu` - у Вас же `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: при добавлении в [3] вылетает

Comment: Вот ссылка на весь код:
https://pastebin.com/jeDPwbYy

Comment: Только там вместо [0] подставьте [qoe]

Answer (score 1):

Все написано правильно (хоть и кривовато) кроме совершенно некорректного `scanf`. И почему вдруг используется формат `%u`, если читается значение типа `unsigned long long`?

```
scanf("%llu", &(*token_dynmass)[0].bedeutung);
```

И уберите ненужные приведения типа при выделении памяти

```
*token_dynmass = malloc(4 * sizeof **token_dynmass);
*token_dynmass = realloc(*token_dynmass, 4 * 1.5 * sizeof **token_dynmass);
```

(Я не спрашиваю даже, почему выделение памяти делается в два этапа.)

И почему данные читаются только для элемента `[0]`? А остальные?

Comment: А `4 * 1.5 * sizeof **token_dynmass` что за магия? `1.5` это что есть? если не секрет. И любопытен размер получаемый на выходе, имхо он явно не достаточный для размещения 4 структур.

Comment: @NewView: В смысле? `4 * 1.5` дает `6.0`. `sizeof **token_dynmass` равно `sizeof(struct token)`. То есть просто выделяется память для `6` элементов. Почему вы решили, что памяти будет недостаточно?

Comment: [bcc32 Error] File1.c(88): E2288 Pointer to structure required on left side of -> or ->*

Comment: @Ant Пишет ошибку на scanf

Comment: Ну так а магическое `6` то откуда? Когда выше указанно `4` ? синтаксис кода сдвигающий голову :) или имелись в виду + размер ссылок?

Comment: Уберите звёздочку: `&(token_dynmass[0]->bedeutung)`

Comment: 6 это поначалу; после будут увеличиваться в 1.5; просто я для удобства не стал весь код писать, а урезал его; Но даже так, при [3] выдает assess Violation

Comment: Тогда падает уже при [2]

Comment: Автор, вот если не сложно, объясните, что конкретно будет увеличиваться на `1.5` ? колличество элементов в массиве? так там целые числа, однако..

Comment: попробуйте выделить память как я предложил, и посмотрите результат, если падает, давайте код целиком, попробуем собрать :) желательно только весь, не кусками.

Comment: Вот весь код: pastebin.com/BhVPjDzH

Comment: Смысл в следующем: 1) Собрать массив структур в 1й функции 2) Отсортировать его во второй 3) Вывести его в 3й
Пока я застрял на первом этапе

Comment: Поэтому выделение поодному не катит, я же не знаю сколько строк на вход подадут ^__^

Comment: @Игорь Буренков: Ой, конечно. После `[0]` нужно уже `.` а не `->`. Исправил в ответе.

Comment: @AnT Огроменное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%Lu", &((*token_dynmass)[qoe].bedeutung));
```